# How exactly getchar() and isblank() works in C

Tags: c, newline, getchar

I am currently learning C and came across this question today. I’m asked to design a function that reads the first word from a line and discards the rest while specifying the maximum number of characters to be read. Below is what I have! Many thanks to you guys in advance!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void get_vol(char * input, int num);
int main(void)
{
    char input[256];
    int num;
    //char ch;
    printf("How many?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    //while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    //    continue;
    get_vol(input, num);
    if (num > 0)
        printf("The word you entered is %s\n", input);
    return 0;
}
void get_vol(char * input, int num)
{
    char ch = 0;
    int i;
    if(num > 0)
    {
        printf("Please enter here:\n");
        do
            ch = getchar();
        while(isblank(ch));
            for(i = 0; !isblank(ch) && i < num; ++i)
            {
                input[i] = ch;
                ch = getchar();
            }
        input[i] = '\0';
    }
    else
        printf("You cannot have less than 1 characters to proceed!\n");
}
```

So here I got two issues. 1)It seems that my get_vol function cannot get rid of the '\n' right after the number been scanned unless I have those three lines intentionally left in comments. So I guess getchar() could not directly skip to the next line, right? Coz I thought my do...while loop in the get_vol() is enough to discard anything before my first word (even a new line). 2)Say, I have maximum 5 characters to be read, and I enter three characters, but in my program, I would need to hit return key three more times before the output shows, so I guess the isblank() did not include the '\n'. I have verified this in Xcode 11.5. It's interesting that according to *C Primer Plus 6th*, '\n' should be included while in 5th, '\n' is not in the list.

Comment: I suggest you [find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). Meaning you break up your complex task into smaller and simpler sub-tasks. Do this until each sub-task can't be further divided. Then implement each little sub-task one by one, testing it before you move on to the next.

Comment: `int ch = 0;`, not `char`. It might seem **as if** it would work with `char` too but it doesn't.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Hi Antti, I see what you mean. But as I want to use char type to get the characters, so how would you suggest me initialize ch?

Comment: The problem alluded to be @AnttiHaapala is that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) actually returns an `int`. This is rather important if you want to compare the result to the `int` value `EOF` (which you really should be doing). And don't worry about it being an `int`, characters in C are almost always promoted to `int` anyway (which is the reason the comparison to `EOF` will be problematic).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude not only, but extended characters can crash in `isblank` if `char`

Comment: the function: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: regarding; `char input[256];
    int num;`    Much better to avoid certain problems by using the Variable Length Array feature of C.  I.E. `int num;  printf("How many?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);   char input[ num+1 ];`  where the +1 is to allow for the terminating NUL byte.   Note: much better to use `size_t` rather than `int` for `num` as that value can never be less than 0.   When calling `scanf()`, always check the returned value.  I.E.  if( scanf( "%zu", &num ) != 1 ) { // handle error }`  where `%zu` is the proper way to input a `size_t`

Comment: regarding; `if(num > 0)`  This test would be better used to avoid calling `get_vol()` rather than cluttering the `get_vol()` function

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you have is that there's a difference between [*space*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) characters and [*blank*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isblank) characters.

Newline is a space character, not a blank.

Comment: Hi buddy! I am not so sure about this. According to C primer Plus 6th, newline is included in blank characters. I just cannot tell the difference between space and blank except that blank has a larger scope.

Comment: @Larry1024 From the linked `isblank` reference: "In the default C locale, only space (0x20) and horizontal tab (0x09) are classified as blank." No newline. Newline is a space ("white-space") character though.

Comment: @Larry1024 (EDIT: removed my incorrect statement about `isblank` not being defined by the C standard.)

Comment: @IanAbbott `isblank` was added in the C99 standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So it was. :) I should have read the Linux man page more carefully.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude & Ian Thank you so much:)! I must have missed something! isspace() works out for both my issues!